# ServiceResponse mocked which gives a null value and not expected this null

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, mockito, junit4

I'm writing j-unit Test-cases for my services and in which i couldn't mock service Response properly, Which is giving me a null. can somebody help me in this issue.

```
public ResponseEntity<Void> lockGet(
        @ApiParam(value = "Unique identifier for this request.", required = true) @RequestHeader(value = "service-id", required = true) String serviceId,
        @ApiParam(value = "Logged in userid.", required = true) @RequestHeader(value = "user-id", required = true) String userId,
        @ApiParam(value = "Unique messageid.", required = true) @RequestHeader(value = "message-id", required = true) String messageId,
        @RequestHeader(value = "access-token", required = true) String accessToken,
        @ApiParam(value = "Unique id of the doamin of the entity", required = true) @RequestParam(value = "lockDomainId", required = true) Long lockDomainId,
        @ApiParam(value = "Unique id of the entity to be fetched", required = true) @RequestParam(value = "lockEntityId", required = true) Long lockEntityId,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    ResponseEntity<Void> result = null;
    if (request.getAttribute("user-id") != null)
        userId = (String) request.getAttribute("user-id");
    String logContext = "||" + lockDomainId + "|" + lockEntityId + "||";
    ThreadContext.put("context", logContext);
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    LOG.info("Method Entry: lockGet" + logContext);
    ServiceRequest serviceRequest = AppUtils.mapGetRequestHeaderToServiceRequest(serviceId, userId, lockDomainId,
        lockEntityId);
    try {
        ServiceResponse serviceResponse = lockService.getLock(serviceRequest);
        // set all the response headers got from serviceResponse
        HeaderUtils.setResponseHeaders(serviceResponse.getResponseHeaders(), response);
        result = new ResponseEntity<Void>(HeaderUtils.getHttpStatus(serviceResponse));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error("Error in lockGet", ex);
        result = new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    ThreadContext.put("responseTime", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - t1));
    LOG.info("Method Exit: lockGet");
    return result;
    }
@Test
    public void testLockGetForError() {
        request.setAttribute("user-id","TestUser");
        ServiceRequest serviceRequest = new ServiceRequest();
        serviceRequest.setUserId("TestUser");
        ServiceResponse serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse();
        LockService service = Mockito.mock(LockService.class);
        when(service.getLock(serviceRequest)).thenReturn(serviceResponse);
//      ServiceResponse serviceResponse = lockService.getLock(serviceRequest);
        ResponseEntity<Void> result = new ResponseEntity<Void>(HeaderUtils.getHttpStatus(serviceResponse));
        ResponseEntity<Void> lockGet = lockApiController.lockGet("1234", "TestUser", "TestMessage", "TestTkn", 12345L, 12345L, request, response);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, lockGet.getStatusCode());
    }
```

I tried in different scenario's which couldn't fix this issue. Can someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this line `when(service.getLock(serviceRequest))` try with `ArgumentMatchers` means `when(service.getLock(ArgumentMatchers.any()))`

Comment: How does the mock: `LockService service = Mockito.mock(LockService.class);` get into the test class `lockApiController`? Mocking in Java is not like Javascript. You have to add the instance of the mock to the class under test thru a constructor, setter, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code that you have put , the issue that i see is that you are actually mocking the `LockService` object but when calling the `lockApiController.lockGet` method the code is not actually **working with the mocked** `LockService` since lockApiController has an LockService object of it's own.

- One way to solve this issue is to inject the mocked `LockService`
  object into the `lockApiController` object using `@Spy`. This way
  when the `getLock()` is called it will be actually called on the
  mocked object and will return the mock response provided.

So in your test :

```
@Test
    public void testLockGetForError() {
        LockService service = Mockito.mock(LockService.class);
        LockApiController lockApiController = Mockito.spy(new LockApiController(service));
        request.setAttribute("user-id","TestUser");
        ServiceRequest serviceRequest = new ServiceRequest();
        serviceRequest.setUserId("TestUser");
        ServiceResponse serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse();
        when(service.getLock(serviceRequest)).thenReturn(serviceResponse);
//      ServiceResponse serviceResponse = lockService.getLock(serviceRequest);
        ResponseEntity<Void> result = new ResponseEntity<Void>(HeaderUtils.getHttpStatus(serviceResponse));
        ResponseEntity<Void> lockGet = lockApiController.lockGet("1234", "TestUser", "TestMessage", "TestTkn", 12345L, 12345L, request, response);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, lockGet.getStatusCode());
    }
```

So you can try passing the mocked `LockService` object to the spy object.

- Another way is to try using the `@InjectMocks` to inject the mocked
  object into the `LockApiController`.

`@InjectMocks` marks a field on which injection should be performed. Mockito will try to inject mocks only either by constructor injection, setter injection, or property injection – in this order. If any of the given injection strategy fail, then Mockito won’t report failure.

For example:

```
@Mock
Map<String, String> wordMap;

@InjectMocks
MyDictionary dic = new MyDictionary();

@Test
public void whenUseInjectMocksAnnotation_thenCorrect() {
    Mockito.when(wordMap.get("aWord")).thenReturn("aMeaning");

    assertEquals("aMeaning", dic.getMeaning("aWord"));
}
```

For the class:

```
public class MyDictionary {
    Map<String, String> wordMap;

    public MyDictionary() {
        wordMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }
    public void add(final String word, final String meaning) {
        wordMap.put(word, meaning);
    }
    public String getMeaning(final String word) {
        return wordMap.get(word);
    }
}
```

For both of these to work , you must be having a constructor or appropriate setters to set the mock object to the `LockApiController` class.

Reference  : https://howtodoinjava.com/mockito/mockito-annotations/